# C#: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or Property

Tags: c#, object, methods, reference

I feel bad for asking this when there are so many questions that are related but I was not able to find/understand the answer I am looking for.

// 2. Develop a program to convert currency X to currency Y and visa versa.

```
using System;

class Problem2
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine ("1. Currency Conversion from CAD to Won");
            Console.WriteLine ("2. Currency Conversion from Won to Cad");
            Console.Write ("Choose from the Following: (1 or 2)? ");
            int option = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
            //double x;
            if (option == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Type in the amount you would like to Convert CAD to Won: ");
                //double y =double.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
                //Console.WriteLine( cadToWon( y ) );
                Console.WriteLine( cadToWon( double.Parse( Console.ReadLine() ) ));
            }
            if (option == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Type in the amount you would like to Convert Won to CAD: ");
                Console.WriteLine( wonToCad (double.Parse( Console.ReadLine())));
            }
        }
    }

    double cadToWon( double x )
    {
        return x * 1113.26;
    }

    double wonToCad( double x)
    {
        return x / 1113.26;
    }
}
```

This give me the Error messgae "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Problem2..." I know that I'll be able to run the program if I add static infront of the methods but I'm wondering why I need it (I think it's because Main is static?) and what do I need to change in order to use these methods without adding static to them?

Thank you

Comment: Kinda funny that everybody didn't answer the question and went directly to "Make them static" while the question was why and how to do it without static?

Comment: Yeah lol but people heard you and included an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your Main method is static, cadToWon and wonToCad *also* have to be static if you want to call them from Main.

```
static double cadToWon(double x) //...


static double wonToCad(double x) //...
```

The other option would be to break all of the logic of your Main, cadToWon, and wonToCad methods out into a *new class*, and then have you Main method simply set up and run that new class.  But I suspect that might be beyond the scope of your assignment.

---

To answer you question of **why** adding static makes this work:

`static` methods are **shared** across all instances of a class.  So no matter what instance of class `Problem2` you're in, there's only **one** `Main` method that's shared across all of them.

`cadToWon`, however, is an **instance** method.  It belongs to a **particular** instance of class `Problem2`.

As a result, you can't call `cadToWon` from `Main`, since `Main` doesn't know what *instance* of `Problem2` to call `cadToWon` on.  `Main` doesn't know what instance to call `cadToWon` on since `Main` doesn't `belong` to any instance.

Comment: They don't HAVE to be static, and they don't HAVE to be in another class. I admit it's a better design, but it is not a constraint.

Comment: @Marc - of course you're right.  He could create a new instance of the class Problems2, and call cadToWon on that instance from within Main.  I just want to keep things simple for OP.

Comment: He knows that making them static work... His question was why and how to make it work without static? Kinda wierd that everybody answer "make them static" to that question.

Comment: @Marc - indeed.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I added an explanation for him.

Comment: Thank you both Adam and Marc-André

Answer (score 0):

It is because Main, being static, is not assigned to any instance of Problem2. Not knowing at which instance of Problem2 to send the variable, it is unable to call the right method.

Right now, your method doesn't modify any fields of any Problem2. But they could, and that's the whole problem. Which instance of Problem2 should they modify? The static method has no way to know that.

So, if you had initialized an instance of Problem2, you could call its own version of the method from the static Main.

```
Problem2 problem = new Problem2();

problem.cadToWon(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Making your methods `static` will solve that problem. You cannot call an instance member (not preceded with `static`) from a static method (e.g. `static void main(..)`). It either both of them have to be declared `static` or you create the instance of the class in which the methods are and access them through the instance. I don't think you need that here

```
static double cadToWon( double x )
{
    return x * 1113.26;
}

static double wonToCad( double x)
{
    return x / 1113.26;
}
```

Accessing through instance

```
Program2 p2 = new Program2();
double x = p2.wonToCad(10);
```

Comment: "I know that I'll be able to run the program if I add static infront of the methods but I'm wondering why I need it"

Comment: You needed it because `main` is static. My answer includes how to **not** add `static` and still call the methods - creating instance of `Program2`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is exactly the one sought here.
Trying to pass an object from Static Main into a method  in Class: Program is well nigh impossible without:

```
 `Program ProgramInstance = new Program();
 ProgramInstance.ProcessObject(MyObject);`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change them to static, then simply move them to another class, and then inside Main create an object and use the functions.